# finite classes of similarity relation on $n \times n$ matrices over $M_n(\mathbb{F})$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

> Let $\mathbb{F}$ be an infinite field. Assume the similarity relation on $M_n(\mathbb{F})$ and let $C$ be a finite class of this equivalence relation. Prove that $C$ has exactly one member.

Note that we say two matrices $A,B \in M_n(\mathbb{F})$ are *similar* if there exists a matrix $P$ where $B=P^{-1}AP$.

Any idea for solving this problem?

Comment: @DietrichBurde I assumed a finite class with at least two matrices,say, $A$ and $B$. Since $B=PAP^{-1}$ if we define $C=P^{-1}AP$ then $C$ is cleary in the same class with $A,B$ then it seems that we can make infinitly many matrices using this method. But I'm not sure that this solution is correct!

Comment: Stress on **infinite** field.

Comment: Aha! The key is upper triangularizing the matrix

Comment: @Omnomnomnom can you plz explain more?

Comment: If you get the time, you should try to push forward your idea to solving your problem.  Indeed we do want to build up from the idea of two distinct matrices $A,B$ in a similarity class the existence of infinitely many.  We need something more to make the idea into an actual construction.

Answer (score 1):

Thoughts:

Suppose that $A \neq B$ are elements of $C$. Let $P$ be an invertible matrix such that $B = P^{-1}AP$.  Note that $P$ does not commute with $A$. So, there exists an invertible matrix $P$ such that $AP \neq PA$.  We may therefore conclude that there are *infinitely* many invertible matrices that fail to commute with $A$.

Now, note that for invertible matrices $P,Q,$ we have
$$
P^{-1}AP = Q^{-1}AQ \iff A(PQ^{-1}) = (PQ^{-1})A
$$